# [Python ]google app engine deploying the file to server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hello I did a hello world python application in local host and then I deployed it to the google app engine using google application launcher but I don't know where access it inside the google app engine from inside the dashboard.And is there any way through which I can edit the hello world once its uploaded to app engine.

I went through their tutorial but I am stuck right here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot to my knowledge edit the codebase once it's uploaded - it can only be modified locally. If you want to access app engine have a look at appengine.google.com . If you look under "Versions" you'll see some the links to the version(s) of your app.

Comment: Thank you I found no resource on this actually .